# How to gain authorization to perform requested action, specifically create an instance of a service in Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, ibm-watson

I am following the [Developing Watson Applications with BlueMix tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/getting_started/gs-bluemix.shtml) but for some reason when attempting to create an instance via

```
cf create-service DataCache free DataCacheInst
```

I get the following error:

```
FAILED 
Server error, status code: 403, error code: 10003, 
message: You are not authorized to perform the requested action
```

As per the error message I do not have privileges, but I am unsure as to why this is being that I can successfully login with my bluemix credentials, see the marketplace services as instructed in the tutorial, and furthermore when entering the command

```
cf org-users MyOrgName
```

the output is emtpy as though there is no assigned manager whatsoever; output:

```
ORG MANAGER


BILLING MANAGER

ORG AUDITOR
```

Stubbornly, when attempting to set myself as the OrgManager like so,

```
cf set-org-role Username MyOrgName OrgManager
```

I am presented with the following error:

```
FAILED 
Server error, status code: 403: Access is denied.  
You do not have privileges to execute this command.
```

Please advise on how to resolve this issue, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cause of your original error is that your likely don't have the SpaceDeveloper role in the space where you are trying to create the service.  Currently, the space and org management functions are disabled on the CLI [in order to maintain multi region consistency], so go into the Console webui, select your organization name and then "Manage Organizations".  This will allow you to set org and space membership and roles.

Comment: thanks @brian-martin, you were right! seems as though my username got deleted from my own organization... I believe this happened somewhere between when my Bluemix trial expired and its renewal.

Comment: just one more clarification, if the CLI is run through the documented Cloud Foundry environment, what is inconsistent between regions? I feel like managing space and organization from the CLI should be available upon request. Thanks again!

Comment: This explanation should be surfaced in the CLI when the error occurs. It's in no way intuitive that going to the UI and checking a box is how it gets fixed.

Comment: "select your organization name" where do I see that?

Answer (score -3):

You tried to login with the command line tool via the command:

```
cf login
```

I have no problems with your commands.

[Bluemix Command Line Interface Doc](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/cli/cli.html)

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the user's question. He is clearly logged in when he is issuing the above commands